# How to call SetWaitableTimerEx correctly

Tags: winapi, timer, power-management

We have a long standing bug report in Boost.Thread where apparently thread sleeps will wake the computer from sleep on timer elapse (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11368). This is apparently due to the new use of [`SetWaitableTimerEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405521(v=vs.85).aspx) to implement coalescing timer support which we call with a `REASON_CONTEXT` like this:

```
REASON_CONTEXT default_reason_context={0/*POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_VERSION*/, 0x00000001/*POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_SIMPLE_STRING*/, (LPWSTR)L"generic"};
```

If timer firing is causing the PC to wake from sleep, it surely must have something to do with this `REASON_CONTEXT` value.

Can anyone here tell us what the appropriate value to use to not have the PC wake from sleep on timer expiry?

Comment: When the documentation looks strange like that then always have a look-see at the actual SDK declaration.  Right-click > Go To Definition if you use VS, you'll land in WinBase.h.  And you'll see that the WakeContext argument is actually `__in_opt`, not `_IN` as suggested in the MSDN article.  Dollars to donuts, you'll probably like NULL better.

Comment: We know from disassembly that specifying NULL for WakeContext causes the call of SetWaitableTimer() instead (i.e. disables the coalescing timer support). I suppose that might be fine if the expected sleep is longer than a few seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this document from Microsoft: [Windows Timer Coalescing](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/C/5/9C5B2167-8017-4BAE-9FDE-D599BAC8184A/TimerCoal.docx), page 8-9:

> **SetWaitableTimerEx** has two new parameters: *WakeContext* and *TolerableDelay*. You use the *WakeContext* parameter only when you set a timer that can wake the system from a sleep state.

It looks like passing `NULL` for the `WakeContext` parameter is fine and it's the only way `SetWaitableTimerEx` will not wake the system. Timer coalescing should still work.

I tried it in Windows 10 and it seems to work correctly. It doesn't wake the system and also doesn't look like it's just calling `SetWaitableTimer`. It could be different in older versions of Windows though, I haven't tested.

Comment: Looks like I missed that paragraph in that document. Thank you!